# How to fix 403 error what Twilio calls my webhook?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We're using Twilio. We have webhooks set up so that when Twilio receives a call, it forwards it to a URL on our site.

This appears to have been working fine. But now I made a change to the code, and suddenly Twilio is having problems calling the webhook. We don't receive the message, and if I look in the Twilio log, it says it got a 403 error. (I can't swear that this has never happened before. I've never noticed a message to be lost, but maybe I missed it while debugging other errors, attributed a lost message to something else.)

The truly strange part is, about 2/3 of the message that come in are received and processed fine, but about 1/3 get the 403 error. This is on a test server where we don't have any load balancing, so all requests are going to the same instance of our app. The tests I've been doing today are all from the same cell phone to the same Twilio number.

We do have authorization on the app, but the authorization is all on sub-directories, not the top level, and the sub-directory with our web hook has no authorization set up.

The first thing my our web hook now does when it gets called is send me an email with the content of the message from Twilio. (For debugging purposes.) I'm not getting that email, so I'm very confidant it's not getting called. And as I say, I can look at Twilio's log and it says that it received the text message and got a 403 error trying to forward it to my webhook.

The fact that it's only like 1/3 of the time is particularly puzzling. It's from the same number, to the same number, hitting exactly the same URL on the same site. Why would it work sometimes and not other times?

I tried to reproduce the problem on my desktop by calling the URL directly, not going through Twilio, and that does not give the same error. (It occurs to me as I type that the next logical test is to hit the page on the server without going through Twilio.)

Oh, the server is ASP.NET. The code is in VB but I doubt that matters as we're not getting as far as executing any of our code when it fails. When it doesn't get the 403, the code is working fine.

Comment: Is there any more information on the `403` in the Twilio Debugger? Where are you running this? Do you have a firewall in front of it? An AWS WAF for example could catch it and return a `403` producing what you see, it looks to Twilio as a `403` and never reaches your code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the "Twilio Debugger". If I look in the Twilio message log, it says source component 14100, httpresponse 403, errorcode 11200, loglevel error, msg "forbidden", emailnotification "false". We are running on AWS. I'm not sure what sort of firewalls we may have, I can check with out network guy who configures such things. It's comming in as an https post request, and this is a public web site that anyone can access, so I don't see why a firewall would block it. And as I said, it usually works and only sometimes doesn't. And if I knew what the problem was, I wouldnt be asking

Comment: I talked to our network guy and indeed the 403 was being generated by the firewall. He added an entry to the white list for Twilio and that appears to have solved the problem. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I'm glad the problem is solved Jay! I added it as an answer.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, but on my Mac my firewall is turned off. Any other suggestions why I could be getting the 403 forbidden error on ngrok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **firewall configuration** as it might block the requests.

If it does then **whitelist** requests originating from Twilio.

We're using AWS WAF and ran into a similar situation: We saw the requests erroring out with a `403` in the Twilio Debugger but the requests never hit our endpoints. Once we adjusted the whitelist the problem was gone.

Comment: Just to add a detail: The AWS firewall was blocking some Twilio requests as "cross site scripting". Our network guy tells me that requests from Twilio say in the header that the user agent is "Twilio proxy" (or something like that), so he white listed it on the basis of that user agent.