# How to fix a 403 forbidden error when sending a text using Twilio and waiting for response from server?

Tags: python, http-status-code-403, ngrok

I am using **webhooks** to try and get a response from my texts using Twilio. However, I am getting a `403 forbidden error` when I send a message to the server, and of course not getting a response as a result. My firewall is turned off on my Mac so I know it's not that blocking it.

Here are some more details from ngrok:

```
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I-Twilio-Idempotency-Token: f44545da-e917-46e6-b24b-e9bf6f727a49
X-Forwarded-For: 3.93.218.220
X-Twilio-Signature: F5mURKfEP6sM/DMGiOFcYPD7lKo=
Host: 843e-167-98-155-255.eu.ngrok.io
User-Agent: TwilioProxy/1.1
Acceptance encoding: gzip 
X-forwarded protocol: https
```

Let me know if any other details are required- I couldn't get logs from ngrok.

I found a similar post, but I checked and my firewall is NOT turned on: [How to fix 403 error what Twilio calls my webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65946401/how-to-fix-403-error-what-twilio-calls-my-webhook)